# Invalid value for redirectUrl following active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-web

Tags: azure, active-directory

Using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-web I get this error:
TypeError: Invalid value for redirectUrl.The URL must be valid and be https://

My config.js contains redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/'

Using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true, // For development only
set this in your config.js file
```